# VectorDrawable with GoogleMap BitmapDescriptor

Tags: android, google-maps, vector-graphics

I have problem with google maps `BitmapDescriptor` while creating icon for `MarkerOptions` using `VectorDrawable`, API 5.0+

Method used for creation:

```
@NonNull
private BitmapDescriptor getBitmapDescriptor(int id) {
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(id);
}
```

Everything works great when `id` argument contains png drawable, however if I try it with `VectorDrawable` defined in xml, App always crash when `googleMap.addMarker(marker)` (`BitmapDescriptor` is not null).

```
11-05 10:15:05.213 14536-14536/xxx.xxxxx.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xxx.xxxxx.app, PID: 14536
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.a.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.dn.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.dm.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.ag.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.eu.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addMarker(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
        at xxx.xxxxx.app.ui.details.DetailActivity.lambda$initGoogleMaps$23(DetailActivity.java:387)
        at xxx.xxxxx.app.ui.details.DetailActivity.access$lambda$10(DetailActivity.java)
        at xxx.xxxxx.app.ui.details.DetailActivity$$Lambda$13.onMapReady(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzl$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.av.a(SourceFile:82)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.fa.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

It doesn't matter how i retrieve drawable, tried creating bitmap using `BitmapFactory.fromResources` and later `BitmapDescritpionFactory.fromBitmap` but results are the same. It just won't work with vector drawable. Tried different vectors as well but it's seems that vector complexity is not the issue here.

Does anyone know how to fix this crash?

@edit

It seems like the problem wasn't with the `BitmapDescriptior` itself, but rather with loading `VectorDrawable` which was returning incorrect bitmap. However solution proposed in answer is still fine.

Comment: This is a known issue. See https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9011

Comment: Yep, but there was previously no link from here to that issue and I thought it would be useful. When the issue eventually gets fixed, that's where it'll be made clear.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Possible workaround:

```
private BitmapDescriptor getBitmapDescriptor(int id) {
    Drawable vectorDrawable = context.getDrawable(id);
    int h = ((int) Utils.convertDpToPixel(42, context));
    int w = ((int) Utils.convertDpToPixel(25, context));
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);
}
```

Comment: Rather than calculating the height and width, you can use `VectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight/Width()`. Unless you're actually trying to scale the graphics

Comment: Actually I'm doing the scaling there, however it may be usefull for others

Comment: In case you are < 21. Use `Drawable vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, id);` instead

Answer (score 18):

According to [the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9011) ([posted by vaughandroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548447/vectordrawable-with-googlemap-bitmapdescriptor#comment60595118_33548447) - thanks!) using a VectorDrawable won't be supported for the time being. See the [comment in the bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827905#comment23) for more information.

Here's the suggested workaround from the Google Maps team:

```
/**
 * Demonstrates converting a {@link Drawable} to a {@link BitmapDescriptor},
 * for use as a marker icon.
 */
private BitmapDescriptor vectorToBitmap(@DrawableRes int id, @ColorInt int color) {
    Drawable vectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), id, null);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(vectorDrawable, color);
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

used this way:

```
// Vector drawable resource as a marker icon.
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(ALICE_SPRINGS)
            .icon(vectorToBitmap(R.drawable.ic_android, Color.parseColor("#A4C639")))
            .title("Alice Springs"));
```

Tinting of the vector is a bonus

Answer (score 12):

Or you could simply use [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlfXNser96AIVCbLtCh01iwuIEAAYASAAEgLBpPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#core)

e.g:

```kotlin
val markerBitmap = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_marker, null)?.toBitmap()
val icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerBitmap)
val marker = MarkerOptions().icon(icon)
```

Reference: [`.toBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/package-summary#tobitmap)

Comment: how do we change the color/tint of the vector with this?

Answer (score 6):

Here is another reference:
http://qiita.com/konifar/items/aaff934edbf44e39b04a

```
public class ResourceUtil {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

private static Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawableCompat vectorDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

public static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, @DrawableRes int drawableResId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableResId);
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawableCompat) {
        return getBitmap((VectorDrawableCompat) drawable);
    } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
        return getBitmap((VectorDrawable) drawable);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported drawable type");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`VectorDrawable` to `BitmapDescriptor` without tint

```
private BitmapDescriptor getBitmapDescriptor(@DrawableRes int id) {
        Drawable vectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), id, null);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Thanks @lbarbosa

Answer (score 3):

the same on Kotlin

```
private fun getBitmapDescriptorFromVector(id: Int, context: Context): BitmapDescriptor {
    var vectorDrawable: Drawable = context.getDrawable(id)
    var h = (24 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density).toInt();
    var w = (24 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density).toInt();
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h)
    var bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    var canvas = Canvas(bm)
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas)
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm)
}
```

EDIT 
@ CoolMind you are totally right, thanks - edited

Comment: If for some reason you use nullable `context`, then why you write: `context?.getDrawable(id)!!`? It will crash with Kotlin NPE in case `context == null`.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin Version

```
private fun getBitmapDescriptor(context: Context, id: Int): BitmapDescriptor? {
    val vectorDrawable: Drawable?
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        vectorDrawable = context.getDrawable(id)
    } else {
        vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id)
    }
    if (vectorDrawable != null) {
        val w = vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth
        val h = vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight

        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h)
        val bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        val canvas = Canvas(bm);
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);

        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: how do we change the color/tint of the vector with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest solution because it hides the implementation in an extension function of MarkerOptions:

```kotlin
fun MarkerOptions.icon(context: Context, @DrawableRes vectorDrawable: Int): MarkerOptions {
    this.icon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorDrawable)?.run {
        setBounds(0, 0, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        draw(Canvas(bitmap))
        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    })
    return this
}
```

So the final result should look like this when used:

```kotlin
MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).icon(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_my_location_map)
```

It's especially useful if you have multiple maps in different places in your app so you don't need to copy/paste the implementation to multiple classes.