# Tint custom icon used in Google Maps API

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Maps view in an Android application and has created a custom marker icon (from svg) like this:

**Useage**

```
mMap.addMarker {
    position(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude))
    title("Path marker")
    icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(this@DrivingActivity, R.drawable.ic_marker))
    anchor(0.5F,0.5F)
    flat(true)
}
```

**Method**

```
private fun bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context: Context, vectorResId: Int): BitmapDescriptor? {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId)?.run {
        setBounds(0, 0, 44, 36)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(44, 36, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        draw(Canvas(bitmap))
        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

How can I add a tint color like you do in ImageViews? The goal is to reuse the same image resource for multiple purposes - it is just the color that will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a ot of inspiration from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44140446/1012636) and got this solution:

I created this method:

```
private fun vectorToBitmap(@DrawableRes id: Int, @ColorInt color: Int, width: Int, height: Int): BitmapDescriptor? {
    val vectorDrawable: Drawable? = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, id, null)

    if(vectorDrawable != null) {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(vectorDrawable, color)
        vectorDrawable.setTintBlendMode(BlendMode.DARKEN)
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas)

        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    }

    return null
}
```

It is used like this:

```
mMap.addMarker {
    position(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude))
    title("Path marker")
    icon(vectorToBitmap(R.drawable.ic_bale, Color.parseColor("#FFCA22"), 44, 33))
    //icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(this@DrivingActivity, R.drawable.ic_bale))
    anchor(0.5F,0.5F)
    flat(true)
}
```

The darken blend mode will recolor white areas while leaving black areas out.